# IN FLEX SLIDER prevoius and next button remove browser back icon click slider previous slide slide

Tags: php

```
  $a =jQuery('.flexslider');
  $a.flexslider({
    slideshow: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    animation: "slide",
    smoothHeight: true,
    touch:true,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav:false,
    start: function(slider){
     jQuery('.slides li .gift1 a', slider).click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
       localStorage.setItem('sliderPagination','slider2');
     });
   },


 });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to do, I don't quite understand that headline. How is this related to `PHP`?

Comment: Please correct your tags as code provided is javascript, not php also elaborate more on the issue it is not clear what you are asking.